# FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame

Tags: android-studio

I recently started seeing this message in Android Studio’s Logcat while running my app, and I’m not sure what is causing it or how to resolve it. Googling has failed me.

E/FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame. [imageOfTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w89gf.png)
this trace comes out when I replace the fragment in the activity with fragmentmanager

I found the source of the error message: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/libs/gui/FrameTimestamps.cpp#258
but I’m not sure why the frame is null

Any help resolving this issue would be great appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: I get the same error when trying to implement the transitions from this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-motion-android/#4

Comment: Are you sure your initiating the right fragment?

Comment: i get the same error when i switch the phone mode from light to dark or dark light.

Comment: If you are using FAB library from 
com.leinardi.android:speed-dial:3.2.0
then revert back to 3.1.1. I faced the same performance issue while using 3.2.0. Reverting back to 3.1.1 solved it.

Comment: Any further findings on this? I am seeing it after trying to implement a shared element transition.

Comment: @Guilejfwe Hi... I gat the same case like yours, did you find any solution ?

Comment: I am also experiencing this error and for me, it simply displays a white screen. Adding permission to the manifest file didn't do it for me.

Comment: I get the same error, when I open Player Screen. I using VLC player and FFMPeg to decode h264 video. And also get data from WebSocket. I don't know why, but I get this error only, when App plays video

Comment: I get the same error when I load a webpage on in_app_webview.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in my flutter app when trying to add google maps and it wasn't loading the map. I realized that my google maps Api key was not set properly in the Androidmanifest.xml file. Also check for any duplicate keys set in case. After correcting the Api key uninstall the old build and install a new one (this is necessary as running the app again on the old build didn't work for me).

Answer (score -26):

if you are using flutter and you are viewing a white screen instead of the map kindly ensure you have the manifest file configured with location access    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`